# Update Oracle statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 2 fields `code` and `house`

```
code                                house 

01-001-0001-0001-0001                 6
01-001-0001-0001-0002                 6 
01-001-0001-0001-0003                 6
01-001-0001-0001-0004                 6
01-001-0001-0001-****                 6

01-001-0001-0002-0001                 8
01-001-0001-0002-0002                 8
01-001-0001-0002-0003                 8
01-001-0001-0002-****                 8
```

How can I update house = null to obtain

```
code                                house 

01-001-0001-0001-0001                 6
01-001-0001-0001-0002                  
01-001-0001-0001-0003                 
01-001-0001-0001-0004                 
01-001-0001-0001-****

01-001-0001-0002-0001                 8
01-001-0001-0002-0002                 
01-001-0001-0002-0003
01-001-0001-0002-****
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
update t
    set house = NULL
    where code not like '%-0001';
```

If you just want this as the result of a `select` query:

```
select code,
       (case when code like '%-0001' then house end) as house
from t;
```